# Scrapy : unable to scrape some information on a website

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am crawling and scraping data from the following website using scrapy:

http://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=4&suggestChosen=true&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=data+scien&headSiteSrch=%2FJob%2Fjobs.htm&sc.keyword=data+scientist&locT=&locId=

Following is my goal:

1. Go through each page
2. In each page, scrape all links result
3. Go into each link from # 2 and scrape data

I am able to do all 3, but got stuck in scraping some of the data.
As an example, below is the link to a page that I want to scrape:

http://www.glassdoor.com/job-listing/lead-data-scientist-director-of-data-science-marketing-cloud-platform-affinity-solutions-JV_IC1147436_KO0,69_KE70,88.htm?jl=1537438396

I am able to scrape job title, company name and location from the top of the page using the following xpaths:

```
item['Company'] = response.xpath('//span[@class = "ib"]/text()').extract()
item['jobTitle'] = response.xpath('//div[@class = "header cell info"]/h2/text()').extract()
item['Location'] = response.xpath('//span[@class = "subtle ib"]/text()').extract()
```

However, I am not able to scrape info from the "Company Info" section.
Below is my code to scrape website, size, headquarters and industry:

```
item['Website'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="InfoDetails"]/div[1]/span[@class = "empData website"]/a/@href').extract()
item['HQ'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="InfoDetails"]/div[2]/span[@class = "empData"]/text()').extract()
item['Size'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="InfoDetails"]/div[3]/span[@class = "empData"]/text()').extract()
item['Industry'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="InfoDetails"]/div[6]/span/tt/text()').extract()
```

I have no idea why these last 4 xpaths don't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The webpage you are scraping is dynamic (need to be rendered by javascript engine). Scrapy only sees plain source code.

Comment: @kev is correct, the web page loads additional information for the company using an XHR call for `http://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/companyOverviewBasicInfoAjax.htm?&employerId=20496&title=Company+Info&linkCompetitors=true`. The `20496` ID can be found in the page HTML source code.

Answer (score 0):

Most crawlers do not render javascript. To get that rendering done you would need to leverage a javascript rendering engine. If you are tied to python then I suggest [using Splash with scrapy as talked about here](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/). Other tools like phantomjs can be integrated for other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late, but just in case someone else need it.
The Glassdoor generates those attributes dynamically, so I used splash request to handle them.
Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
id = 1
class GlassdoorData(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'glassdoordata'
#allowed_domains = ['https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11.htm']
start_urls = ['https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11.htm']
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(
        url,
        self.parse,
        args={'wait': 10},
        )   

def parse(self, response):
    #main_url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca"
    urls = response.css('li.jl > div > div.flexbox > div > a::attr(href)').extract()

    for url in urls:            
            url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca" + url
            yield SplashRequest(url = url, callback = self.parse_details,args={'wait': 10})
    global id
    id = id+1
    #if id < 2 :
    next_page_url = "https://www.glassdoor.ca/Job/canada-data-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IN3_KE7,11_IP{}.htm".format(id) 
    if next_page_url:

         #next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url) 
       #self.log("reached22: "+ next_page_url)

       yield SplashRequest(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse,args={'wait': 10},) 



def parse_details(self,response):
    yield{
        'Job_Title' : response.css('div.header.cell.info > h2::text').extract_first(),
      'Company' : response.css('div.header.cell.info > span.ib::text').extract_first(),
      'Location' : response.css('div.header.cell.info > span.subtle.ib::text').extract_first(),
      'Website' : response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/span/a/text()").extract(),
      'Size' : response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/label[contains(text(),'Size')]/following-sibling::span/text()").extract(),
      'Industry' : (response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/label[contains(text(),'Industry')]/following-sibling::span/text()").extract_first()).lstrip(),
      'Type' : (response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/label[contains(text(),'Type')]/following-sibling::span/text()").extract_first()).lstrip(),
      'Revenue' : (response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/label[contains(text(),'Revenue')]/following-sibling::span/text()").extract_first()).lstrip(),
      'Competitors' : (response.xpath("//div[@class = 'infoEntity']/label[contains(text(),'Competitors')]/following-sibling::span/text()").extract_first()).lstrip(),

    }
```

Edit the settings.py like this:

```
BOT_NAME = 'glassdoordata'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['glassdoordata.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'glassdoordata.spiders'



# Obey robots.txt rules
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
 }

 SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.99.100:8050'

 SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
 }

 DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
 HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'



 ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

You need to install Splash before running this program.

Thanks